# Вывести значение модели Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.7

есть модель Comment

в ней делаю функцию вывода значения like для пользователя. Если он лайнкул то 1, если дизлайк то 0

```
public function islike(){
        $likes = CommentLike::where('comment_id', $this->id)->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->first();
        return $likes->like;
    }
```

при выводе комментариев

```
<button class="btn-like">
   <svg><use xlink:href="#like"></use></svg>
   span class="like-count">{{ $comment->likes() }} - {{$comment->islike()}}</span>
</button>
<button class="btn-like dislike">
   <svg><use xlink:href="#like"></use></svg>
   <span class="dislike-count">{{ $comment->dislikes() }} - {{$comment->islike}}</span>
 </button>
```

хочу вывести значение, но пишет

```
ErrorException
Undefined offset: 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Уважаемый @Uvasya, сообщение об ошибке `Undefined offset: 1` свидетельствует о попытке обращения к элементу массива с индексом **1**, тогда как элемент массива с таковым индексом отсутствует. Поскольку в приведенном Вами коде попыток обратиться к элементу массива не наблюдается, можно сделать логичный вывод: Вы накосячили где-то **вне** приведенного кода. В сообщении об ошибке, поскольку это Laravel и ошибка отловлена исключением, абсолютно однозначно указаны имя файла и строка, в которой ошибка была обнаружена. А если Вы накосячили где-то с передачей аргументов - то место ошибки Вы также можете отследить по трассировке вызовов на той же странице с отображением ошибки.

> "Ищите - и обрящете", как говорил товарищ Христос. (с) "В августе сорок четвертого"